# How to create a project to show role based authorization in asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014, role-base-authorization

I have gone through some links on Google. But all are very confusing. I am new to MVC, so I can't solve some issues.

Comment: Please elaborate, it is not at all clear what you are asking. Are you creating a specific project? What kind of project is this, and how many users will it have, and what kind of different groups / levels of users? Do you want a solution for managing users, or just a way to show info about existing roles/users? **Please give as much context as possible, and then try to ask a clear and specific question**.

Comment: @Kjartan It is just a sample project to use role based authorization. There are two types of users. One is admin and another one is employee. There are three pages. I want admin to access all the pages. But employee can only see one page i.e index page. Admin can delete and add employee. For this how can I use role based authorization using membership identity? Please help.